# Unique custom string hash

Tags: string, hash, jvm, unique, hashcode

I know that `hashCode()` in the JVM can't make a string's hash unique due to the variety of possible characters.

But suppose we only have 256 unique characters. Would this formula produce a unique hash for every possible String?

```
string[0] * 256^0 + string[1] * 256^1 + ... + string[length-1] * 256^(length-1).
```

Where `string[x]` is the encoding of my character.

Note `string[x]` must be in the range `[1, 256]`, we cannot include 0 or it would make a collision possible.

Comment: Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function ?

Comment: well, not quite. The question is if it would be unique and this all. Space needs are not important for me.

Comment: If you're storing the hash value as an fixed sized int, you will run out of possible hash values before you run out of possible strings, so, no, you won't get a unique hash value for all possible strings.

Comment: @andand true, but i am only interested if that would be unique. In my task string can only have 6 characters.

Comment: @DankoPenko then why do you _even_ mention 256 to begin with?

Comment: @Eugene because by assumption we have 256 characters available

Comment: @DankoPenko you already have an answer. 256 characters: you cant generate unique ids. 6 characters - you can, at leats if we are talking about an `int`. Now, what is your actual question?

Comment: @Eugene sorry, i put it wrong. String can be max 6 characters long. And there is 256 characters available.

Comment: When you do not limit the result value space, this formula is a no-op. That’s just how interpreting a sequence of bytes as integer number works. Of course, re-interpeting *n* distinct byte sequences as *n* distinct numbers is a lossless projection. And, as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60217291/2711488), it’s not a hash function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a character space of size 256, then all you're really doing here is [converting from base 256 to base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_of_the_numeral_system). So yes, every possible string in your alphabet will be mapped to a unique integer.

That said, this isn't really a hash function since this is an injective function from your 256-alphabet string space to the natural numbers (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). The only reason it's not a bijection is because you're domain is [1, 256] instead of [0, 255] (which doesn't matter for what you have above).

As @andand said if there's a max value then you'll definitely hit collisions, and if there's no max value then this isn't really a `hash` function.

Comment: There is no conversion to base 10 in the example code.

Comment: His strings/characters are essentially [base-256 integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system#Positional_systems_in_detail), with whatever the 256 characters are. The "hash" function is essentially converting from base to a decimal value.

Comment: The OP’s function just produces an integer number. Numbers are not in a particular base system per se. But everyone should know that computers are calculating in the base-2 system. Don’t get confused by the fact that converting numbers to a string will use the decimal system by default. As long as the OP doesn’t print the number, this is not happening.